# How to check all type of file and display the validation message while uploading file using PHP

Tags: php, file

I need to upload the below type of file using PHP.

```
1-.png,
2-.jpeg
3-.jpg
4-.pdf,
5-.ppt
6-.docx and excel sheet.
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onSubmit="javascript:return checkForm();" action="complain.php">

<div style="color:#F00; text-align:center;"> <?php  echo $error; ?></div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Upload Document :</span>
<input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="uploadme" id="bannerimage" onChange="javascript:displayImage(event);">
</div>
</form>
```

> complain.php:

```
$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($imageName);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["uploadme"]["tmp_name"]);
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") {
      echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG files are allowed.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
   }
```

Here i can only up to image type files. Here i need all files which is given above  should check and if any error is coming it will display inside the form.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<?php
$allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg');
$filename = $_FILES['uploadme']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
echo 'error';
}
```

?>

Comment: I need all type of file for upload .Please read my post again.

Comment: You can sepecify all the extention in $allowed array.